# How to route all *.dev to subfolders on vagrant box

Tags: apache, vagrant, vhosts, virtual-hosts

I want that every `*.dev` Host will be routed to my vagrant machine to `/var/www/vhosts/*.dev/public`, for example my local development environment `project1.dev` is located in `/var/www/vhosts/project1.dev/public`

So when I add a new (sub)project into my box, I do not need to change my config.yaml (Vagrant installed via puphpet.com) and reload the machine.

On my computer, I added the following to the hosts file in `/private/etc`:

```
192.168.56.101 *.dev
```

On my VM, I changed my `10-default_vhosts80.conf` in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` to:

```
# ************************************
# Vhost template in module puppetlabs-apache
# Managed by Puppet
# ************************************

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName default

  ## Vhost docroot
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/default"

  ## Directories, there should at least be a declaration for /var/www/default

  <Directory "/var/www/default">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  ## Load additional static includes

  ## Logging
  ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/default_vhost_80_error.log"
  ServerSignature Off
  CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/default_vhost_80_access.log" combined

  ## Custom fragment
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/default/$1
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *.dev:80>
    ServerName dev
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/%0
</VirtualHost>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Any ideas? I am a beginner in this subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I use [dnsmasq](http://passingcuriosity.com/2013/dnsmasq-dev-osx/) to route all `.localdev` Domains to 127.0.0.1. Note that I am using `.localdev` instead of just `.dev` or `.local` as this seems to cause problem (OS X 10.10) because  `.dev` is a [proposed gTLD](http://icannwiki.com/.dev) and `.local` is used by [Apple's Bonjour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local).

Then I configured Apache by creating and enabling this site:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAlias localhost *.localdev #wildcard catch all
  VirtualDocumentRoot /hosts/%1/public
  UseCanonicalName Off
  <Directory "hosts">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

(from: http://brunodbo.ca/blog/2013/04/26/setting-up-wildcard-apache-virtual-host-wildcard-dns)

Answer (score 2):

I use a [proxy auto configuration file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config). This works on Windows, MacOS and Linux. Easy, [flexible](https://findproxyforurl.com/pac-functions/) and no additional software required. The following example routes all `*.dev` traffic to your vagrant box:

```js
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    if (dnsDomainIs(host, ".dev")) {
        return "PROXY 127.0.0.1:8080";
    }

    return 'DIRECT';
}
```

When needed, replace `127.0.0.1:8080` with the IP and webserver port of your vagrant box. Store this file somewhere. You can store it locally or let the webserver on your Vagrant-box host the file.

**Windows:** See [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2013/10/11/understanding-web-proxy-configuration/) how to use the PAC file on Windows.

**MacOS:** See [here](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/enter-proxy-server-settings-on-mac-mchlp2591/mac) how to use the PAC file on MacOS. You can link to the file using `file:///Users/username/path/to/proxy.pac`.

**Linux:** For linux it depends, but I'm sure linux users will be able to Google for their specific situation.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately hosts files do not support using wildcards. You have to manually define each and every host to redirect.

Also, your hosts file is at `/etc/hosts`

Comment: I'm gonna try this to add wildcard support: https://code.google.com/p/marlon-tools/source/browse/tools/dnsproxy/dnsproxy.py